# I am having 'browser' must be a non-empty character string Error while authenticating with fbOAuth

Tags: r, rfacebook

```
my_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="", app_secret="")
```

Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings: `http://localhost:1410/`

When done, press any key to continue...

Waiting for authentication in browser...

Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
**Error in utils::browseURL(hu$url) :
  'browser' must be a non-empty character string**

Comment: Set your default browser: `options(browser = 'firefox')`